# Unable to retrieve point where i rendered listview but still in button click event

Tags: android, listview, button

I am  having a listview which has header as button and ( 3 textboxes as row in listview)

Now i want to render the row when i click on button.

So i made an adapter which renders the data in textboxes, now my onCreate() method initially renders the button, then i have button click event in onCreate() so that when i click, it again renders the data in textboxes .
It is doing fine, but i want the data to be flipped with some other data , so i want a position where button renders the listview but do not get out of the click event.

But i am unable to get that point

The point where myviewholder will get the value so that i can change it, that point makes me irritate, its been whole night i am unable to figure out where.

my main activity onclick()

```
onheadbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    int t = randInt(2, 3);

                    ItemBean bean = new ItemBean();

                    bean.setTitle1(Integer.toString(randInt(2, 10)));
                    // bean.setId("1");
                    t--;

                    bean.setTitle2(Integer.toString(randInt(2, 10)));
                    t--;

                    if (t != 0) {
                        bean.setTitle3(Integer.toString(randInt(2, 10)));
                        t--;
                    }
                    if (t != 0) {



                    itemList.add(0, bean);

                    adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                            itemList);

                    listviewwithbutton.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

            });
```

my adapter

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Object> itemList;
    public ViewHolder holder0;

    public Activity context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Object> itemList) {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;

        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);

            /*
             * holder.imgViewLogo = (ImageView) convertView
             * .findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);
             */
            holder.txtViewTitle1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            holder.txtViewTitle2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.txtViewTitle3 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView3);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) itemList.get(position);


        holder.txtViewTitle1.setText(bean.getTitle1());
        holder.txtViewTitle2.setText(bean.getTitle2());
        holder.txtViewTitle3.setText(bean.getTitle3());

        return convertView;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly:

> i want a position where button renders the listview but do not get out of the click event. But i am unable to get that point

So you are saying you want to have something execute while the button is maintaining a clicked state and then have something else happen ("the data to be flipped with some other data") upon exiting the click event?

If so, I would set an `OnTouchListener` on the button rather than an OnClickListener, since that will supply your callbacks with a `MotionEvent`.

So you could have:

```
onheadbutton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Do some stuff while in the clicked state
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Do some other stuff while exiting the clicked state
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it actually works.
but my button state remains clicked , what can i do about it. I tried setclickable but nothing change seems

Comment: What do you mean by your "button state"? You mean how it looks visually, or something else?

Comment: I mean when i click it, it becomes blue ( clicked state ) but then it remains in that state only. Even though i can click it again but state seems same